# How to send user information through directline botconnector

Tags: javascript, botframework, botconnector

I'm building a mobile client to talk to a bot built with microsoft botbuilder through botconnector directline. I want to send things like the unique id of the user speaking with the bot, so my bot can operate on this user. Currently I'm just POSTing to directline, but when I add additional things in the body, my bot can't retrieve it. I'm probably doing something really simple wrong. Would love to get your help on this!

POST code from client:

```
sendToBot: function(setUpObj, message, returnCallback){
    var postURL=baseURL+"/"+setUpObj.conversationId+"/messages"
    var postOptions ={
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
           "Authorization": setUpObj.conversationToken,
           "content-type": "application/json"
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
         "text": message,
         "from": {
           'address': setUpObj.currentUserUid
         }
       })
     }


    fetch(postURL, postOptions)
      .then(
        (response)=>response.text()
      )
      .then(
        (responseText)=>{
                this.getResponse(setUpObj, returnCallback)
        }
      )


  }
```

and I'm accessing the the currentUserUid on the server by

```
session.message.from.address
```

Thanks for you patience.

Comment: please provide sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `channelData` in the json? It's described as "data sent unmodified between client and bot" and can look like:

```
{
  "id": "CuvLPID4kDb|000000000000000004",
  "conversationId": "CuvLPID4kDb",
  "created": "2017-02-22T21:19:51.0357965Z",
  "from": "examplebot",
  "text": "Hello!",
  "channelData": {
    "examplefield": "abc123"
  }
}
```

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/channeldata/

So in your code it could look like:

```
var postOptions ={
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
       "Authorization": setUpObj.conversationToken,
       "content-type": "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     "text": message,
     "channelData": {
       "from": {
        "address": setUpObj.currentUserUid
       }
     }
   })
 }
```